# Issues with .bat sharing Folder on Network (net share)

Tags: batch-file, network-share

I'm having an issue with net share. Basically if it's a new share it works perfectly. However existing shares I cannot modify the roles with net share?

Steps to reproduce my problem (As I am having a hard time putting it into words)

Step 1: Create a new folder at `C:\My Test\StackOverview`

Step 2: Run the following .bat

```
net share StackOver /DELETE
net share StackOver="C:\My Test\StackOverview" /GRANT:Everyone,READ
```

Result: When user "testuser" attempts to access files it works perfect.

Step 3: Now create a new folder at `C:\My Test\NotWorking`

Step 4: In Windows (Not with a .bat) right click the folder and Share this folder with specific people but insure "testuser" isn't one of them

Step 5: After the folder is shared run the following .bat

```
net share NotWorking /DELETE
net share NotWorking="C:\My Test\NotWorking" /GRANT:Everyone,READ
```

Result: "testuser" cannot access this folder. It says he doesn't have the correct permissions. I would expect the script to work either way? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permissions for the individual user.

```
net share NotWorking="C:\My Test\NotWorking" /GRANT:testuser,READ
```

Comment: Same problem. I did read a bit more onto this topic however and it appears that you can only create new shares with "net share" and you cannot modify already shared files. So I think this is impossible and I have to use another tool to change the permissions. Just figured there'd be a easier way in Windows Batch File. Thanks!

Comment: Could you delete the share with `/Delete` then re-add?

Comment: I have been doing that. I believe my question /Delete the share no?